# API Mgt (Traffic and DAS) ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver} - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I am trying to configure that Traffic Manager Das Agent to pooling events in DAS.

But I am with the below error:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver} -  Error while reading from the socket.  {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver}
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

I am to using the Digital Certificate default wso2 (localhost) and the Balancer F5 (One Digital certificate to VIP IP the balancer trafficManager).

Someone can help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try by importing F5 balancer certificate to the client trust store of the traffic manager